# Usage of the word: realpolitik

Tags: word-usage

Can the word realpolitik correctly be used to describe how a country deals with its citizens, or only between countries to describe a form of diplomacy?

If not, what word best describes my example?

Comment: Since this is with regards to special vocabulary usage, this might get more thorough answers at history.SE

Answer (score 2):

The German word ***realpolitik*** was coined in 1853 by the writer Ludwik von Rochau. It refers to politics based on power and practical matters as opposed to ideology.

It seems to have been a child of the 1848 revolutions across Europe, a clash between Enlightenment ideology and the reality of the European states system as it then existed.

***Realpolitik*** may have been seen as a way of accommodating enlightened change through essentially practical means.

The word's meaning has changed slightly as it has become adopted into other European languages. There is a good Wikipedia article on the subject which I suggest to anyone interested.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realpolitik

Answer (score 0):

[Realpolitik](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/realpolitik)

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>
> A system of politics or principles based on practical
>   rather than moral or ideological considerations:

This definition implies no distinction between international and domestic politics.

Answer (score 0):

As an AE speaker with an advanced degree in politics, I'd say yes, the definition does not explicitly refer to only foreign policy. However, it is almost solely used for foreign policy in AE.

Personally, I haven't ever heard it in the context of domestic politics or policy and would consider it incorrect if someone used it in this way.